# How to view duplicate tests in sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

In sonar I can see the code coverage but is it possible to view the duplicate tests in sonar ?

Thanks you.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SonarQube 3.5, it is possible to see which test class(es) covered a specific line of code. So this means that when you see that a line has been executed 5 times by unit tests, you will be able to easily see which tests were executed and so find duplicate tests.

For that, please read the ["Mapping of Unit Tests and Covered Code"](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project#CodeCoveragebyUnitTestsforJavaProject-MappingofUnitTestsandCoveredCode) section of the documentation. You will have to download the sample application in order to see how to configure your POM to activate this feature.